# Afther make a Minimap my player move slowly in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a video game in Unity, and I have a minimap with a Texture Render of the room and an orthogonal Camera for the minimap. The thing is that the minimap is fine in unity's play mode but when I export it to WebGL the map is fine but the character in my scene slows down a lot when moving. If I disable the minimap and export to WebGL it works fine and does not slow down. That could be happening?

This is the code for characterMovements:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovements : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float rotateSpeed = 2.0f;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    GameObject cameraMain;
    float upDownRotation;
    float miny = -45.0f;
    float maxy = 45.0f;

private void Start()
{
    cameraMain = this.transform.Find("Main Camera").gameObject;
}

private void Update()
{
    //definitions
    CharacterController controller = this.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    float yInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    //move forward
    moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, zInput);
    moveDirection = this.transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    moveDirection *= walkSpeed;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

    //Rotate Visitor
    this.transform.Rotate(0, yInput * rotateSpeed, 0);

    //Rotate MainCamera
    upDownRotation += Input.GetAxis("Zaxis") * rotateSpeed;
    upDownRotation = Mathf.Clamp(upDownRotation, miny, maxy);
    cameraMain.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-upDownRotation, 0, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show us your code for moving? It sounds like the additional rendertexture eats up FPS and your movement is frame-rate-dependent ... do you use `Time.deltaTime` for movements?

Comment: Yes I use Time.deltaTime for movements. 
What else do you know about this subject, does it interest me a lot?

Comment: You shouldn't use `GetComponent` in `Update`. Rather use it in `Start` and store the result in a variable (like you do with `cameraMain`).

Comment: some general notes: You should use `cameraMain = Camera.main.gameObject;` (Make sure to tag your main camera `MainCamera`). Your rotation is still frame-rate dependent. The move can be simplified a lot by using `controller.Move(transform.forward * zInput * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` and yes as already said store the `controller` reference *once*. Besides that I don't see an obvious reason for the behavior you describe except as said .. adding a second camera and a rendertexture causes lnger render times and additional draw calls at least eating some performance

Comment: Do you have any specific code for rendering the minimap?
Also, just to make sure, could you check the fps, to know if it is a low fps problem or some movement related suff? In case of low fps I suggest profiling to see what is eating up the resources.